# How to set FTP TRAMP/ANGE connection configuration

Tags: tramp, configuration-files, ftp

With SSH I can add connections to my SSH config file at `/.ssh/config` Once added to the config file emacs will auto-complete these connections when using tramp integrations like `find-file /ssh:`

I would like emacs to auto-complete FTP connection addresses In the same manner. Where can I specify them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general description how to program completion lists in Tramp is given in the [Tramp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Customizing-Completion). For FTP, it is sufficient to use `~/.netrc`.